# adding effect on ajaxbutton success error

Tags: ajax, yii

I'm trying to add effect on rendering result of ajaxbutton in Yii

```
<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Update Data',Yii::app()->createUrl('post/ajax',
   array('post_id' => $data['id'], 'pros_cons'=> 1)),
   array(
     'type'=>'POST',
     'success'=>'js:function(string){ 
        var $thisClicked = $(this);
        $thisClicked.parent().next('.form').html(string).fadeIn(1500).slideDown(1300);
     }'          
));
?>
```

and I got the error :

`syntax error, unexpected '').html(string).fadeIn(1500).s' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'`

anyone can tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the single quotes in the javascript expression with double quotes.

```
'success'=>'js:function(string){ 
    var $thisClicked = $(this);
    $thisClicked.parent().next(".form").html(string).fadeIn(1500).slideDown(1300);
 }'
```